# Se puede poner una tabla dinamicao un grafico dinamico en Access 2016

Tags: ms-access

Buenas Tardes tendo una consulta la cual quisiera hacerlecomo una tabla dinamica para crear un reporte que me salga por defectos los datos. y quisiera saber si es que se puede en access ??

Comment: Bienvenido a SO. Tablas dinámicas como las de Excel, no. Tendrías que hacer todo a través de consultas. Pero hay consultas de agrupamiento y tablas de referencias cruzadas que pueden servirte. Sería mucho mejor si nos pusieras unos datos de ejemplo de lo que tienes, y a dónde te gustaría llegar con esos datos Danos el input y el output

Comment: Vale tengo esto 
Nombre de los medicos y especialidades mas dias de consultas y horas realizadas lo que queria intentar es hacer una tabla dinamica en elmismo access y luego hacer ver las cantidades de una especialidad de un mes como es su afluencia en una clinica

Comment: Insisto, mejor si pones cómo guardas los datos en tus diferentes tablas, y como te gustaría resumirlos en un informe. Solo con palabras es difícil replicar lo que tienes.